# Opened many doors - "for me" or "to me"?

Tags: idioms, prepositions

I'm trying to say that some event in my life has made many achievements in the future possible for me.

Do I say

> it has opened many doors **for me**

or

> it has opened many doors **to me**

?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'm new here and the question's much clearer now.

Comment: To "open doors for me" most idiomatic.  The image is of someone physically holding the door open for another, vs simply unlocking the door.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It has opened many doors for me.

This is the usual and I would say correct version.  Doors have been opened **for** me to go through, **by** the event.

> It has opened many doors to me.

This has a superficial appearance of correctness but that is because of confusion with a very similar idiom. It makes less sense in my opinion.

If we open a door **to** someone, it means we begin on opposite sides of the door e.g.

*I knocked on John's front door and he opened the door to me.*

John could not open a lot of doors *to* me unless, by some weird coincidence, he happened to be inside many different buildings that I visited.

**Summary**

If you open a door **for** someone then you are probably both on the same side of the door. You do so as an act of courtesy and to assist the other person in passing through.  This fits very well with the metaphor.

If you open a door **to** someone then you are almost certainly on opposite sides of the door and the person opening it is letting a visitor  in -- usually to the inside of a building. This makes little sense in terms of an event. An event is not waiting for you inside a series of doors.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker (in the U.S.) *for* sounds correct.

Comment: As a native speaker (in the UK) either *to* or *for* would work equally.

Comment: I live in the US. Both sound correct but might have *slightly* different connotations. The 'for' variant suggests that actable opportunities have arisen as a result of *it*, while the 'to' variant suggests that new experiences/ideas have arisen as a result of *it*. Again, this difference is very small and maybe I'm alone in sensing it.

Comment: I'm from the UK but I don't agree that the two are equivalent. I'll write an answer to show the difference.